# Can C# Web Service Call Other DLL Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll, call

I have a C# web service, and would like to call functions from a another C# DLL that has some DB related functions.

Where do I place the DLL and how do I reference the DLL in my web service for everything to work.

I am brand new to web services, thanks for helping.

Comment: **Sure!** The C# code in your web service implementation is C# code like any other - it can do everything C# can do.... just add a reference to that/those DLL(s) to your project, and off you go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add and call DLL in your web services as same as in any other project. Just right click on the References and select 'Add References' and select the DLL which your want to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the DLL in your Web Service project just like in any other project types. 
Just add the reference of the DLL into your web service project and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'add reference' in the project containing the web service (.asmx file) and then use the dll in the web service method's code behind like you would do normally.

You don't need to copy that DLL over to any client / consuming site or anything like that, since it's literally only the web services that's accessing the dll and the client can 'use' the DLL via the web service layer.

hth